# How do I `import blah from 'http://bar.org/some-esm-module.js'` in the Chrome Devtools JS console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, ecmascript-2016, es6-modules

When I try to use an ESM import from the Chrome devtools / javascript console, it complains:

```
> import Confetti from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti'

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Is there any way to convince the chrome console to execute as `type='module'` so I can use module statements? Or another way to workaround this that still permits interactive imports of ESM modules for interactive development?

I've been switching to heavily using ESM modules, in particular the large library of NPM ESM modules auto-converted by [Skypack](https://skypack.dev). This has worked great in static development, but I'm a heavy REPL / browser devtools user.

Even finding a third-party `fakeImport(urlToESM)` function I could use to load ESM modules would be a huge productivity improvement for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) and top-level `await` should work:

```
const { default: Confetti } = await import('https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti');
```

Comment: `const Confetti = (await import('https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-confetti')).default`

Comment: @cachius same thing

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic import might come in handy.

```
import('/modules/my-module.js')
  .then((module) => {
    // Do something with the module.
});
```

> You can use await with it.

```
let module = await import('/modules/my-module.js');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports